# Empty traces due to some UI/React issues

Tags: zipkin, brave

Traces cannot be displayed due to some UI/React issues.

UI screenshot
[image]

Browser console screenshot
[image]
The issue has been reproduced with both, the elasticsearch and mem storages on the latest version of Zipkin.

Traces are generated by Spring Boot 2.7.0 and Sleuth 3.1.3

Business flow: a chain of Spring Boot micro-services communicating with each others using Kafka, grpc, etc.

See the json at the end of the question.

**It seems the last trace is always working. So, a working trace will be "corrupted" once a new trace will be available in the UI.**
Any link with in flight traces?!

Fee free to ask if you need more details.

This issues makes Zipkin unusable.

[{"traceId":"b4a8d96f8f049083","parentId":"5492d94d22d95e38","id":"e559e302bcccd4cf","name":"gateway query","timestamp":1655379022717351,"duration":1574,"localEndpoint":{"serviceName":"api-adapter","ipv4":"10.129.12.167"},"tags":{"gateway.class":"DefaultQueryGateway","gateway.method":"query","param.type=Class":"class com.mycompany.myproject.service.transactionsearch.api.response.TransactionSearchResponse","param.type=GetTransactionById":"GetTransactionById(transactionType=CCTR, commandMetadata={"command_id":"e51a3413-0628-4d8d-a3dc-8368a2bc1484","command_type":null,"command_key":null,"command_status":"Received","transaction_id":"6823985a-8205-45c2-a3d1-d7d239e3be10","transaction_type":null,"flow_type":null,"flow_id":null,"flow_alternate_id":null,"creation_timestamp":"2022-06-16T11:30:22.716666Z","update_timestamp":"2022-06-16T11:30:22.71667Z","channel_info":{"sender_channel":"API","sender_dn":"ou=application,ou=payment,o=myprojectsbeaa,o=mycompany","sender_bic":null,"sender_role":null,"receiver_channel":null,"receiver_dn":null,"receiver_bic":null,"service_name":"mycompany.cbprplus.02","message_type":null,"is_technical_pde":null,"is_business_pde":null,"adapter_information":{"http_verb":"GET","uri":"/mycompany/payments/customer-credit-transfer/cbprplus/v1/customer-credit-transfers/6823985a-8205-45c2-a3d1-d7d239e3be10"},"command_expiry_time":null,"delivery_expiry_time":null},"resource_info":{"input_reference":"e51a3413-0628-4d8d-a3dc-8368a2bc1484","output_reference":null,"instruction_id":null,"uri":null,"output_id":null,"message_id":null},"command_result":null})","param.type=QueryContext":"QueryContext{replyTimeout=PT10S, topic='null, partition=null, key='null, headers=RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), synchronizationCommands=[]}"}},{"traceId":"b4a8d96f8f049083","parentId":"b4a8d96f8f049083","id":"5492d94d22d95e38","name":"service get-credit-transfer","timestamp":1655379022717042,"duration":1022412,"localEndpoint":{"serviceName":"api-adapter","ipv4":"10.129.12.167"},"tags":{"param.type=GetTransactionById":"GetTransactionById(transactionType=CCTR, commandMetadata={"command_id":"e51a3413-0628-4d8d-a3dc-8368a2bc1484","command_type":null,"command_key":null,"command_status":"Received","transaction_id":"6823985a-8205-45c2-a3d1-d7d239e3be10","transaction_type":null,"flow_type":null,"flow_id":null,"flow_alternate_id":null,"creation_timestamp":"2022-06-16T11:30:22.716666Z","update_timestamp":"2022-06-16T11:30:22.71667Z","channel_info":{"sender_channel":"API","sender_dn":"ou=application,ou=payment,o=myprojectsbeaa,o=mycompany","sender_bic":null,"sender_role":null,"receiver_channel":null,"receiver_dn":null,"receiver_bic":null,"service_name":"mycompany.cbprplus.02","message_type":null,"is_technical_pde":null,"is_business_pde":null,"adapter_information":{"http_verb":"GET","uri":"/mycompany/payments/customer-credit-transfer/cbprplus/v1/customer-credit-transfers/6823985a-8205-45c2-a3d1-d7d239e3be10"},"command_expiry_time":null,"delivery_expiry_time":null},"resource_info":{"input_reference":"e51a3413-0628-4d8d-a3dc-8368a2bc1484","output_reference":null,"instruction_id":null,"uri":null,"output_id":null,"message_id":null},"command_result":null})","service.class":"TransactionServiceImpl","service.method":"getCreditTransfer"}},{"traceId":"b4a8d96f8f049083","parentId":"e559e302bcccd4cf","id":"4b43ec0462bcb4e5","kind":"PRODUCER","name":"send","timestamp":1655379022718231,"duration":9680,"localEndpoint":{"serviceName":"api-adapter","ipv4":"10.129.12.167"},"remoteEndpoint":{"serviceName":"kafka"},"tags":{"kafka.key":"6823985a-8205-45c2-a3d1-d7d239e3be10","kafka.topic":"SEARCH_REQUESTS"}},{"traceId":"b4a8d96f8f049083","parentId":"0456ed78768e0cad","id":"87d2cc1dd1ec534a","kind":"CONSUMER","name":"poll","timestamp":1655379023738987,"duration":1,"localEndpoint":{"serviceName":"api-adapter","ipv4":"10.129.12.167"},"remoteEndpoint":{"serviceName":"kafka"},"tags":{"kafka.topic":"API-ADAPTER-REPLY"}},{"traceId":"b4a8d96f8f049083","id":"b4a8d96f8f049083","kind":"SERVER","name":"get /mycompany/payments/customer-credit-transfer/cbprplus/v1/customer-credit-transfers/{uetr}","timestamp":1655379022715466,"duration":1048463,"localEndpoint":{"serviceName":"api-adapter","ipv4":"10.129.12.167"},"remoteEndpoint":{"ipv4":"10.128.22.1","port":57726},"tags":{"http.method":"GET","http.path":"/mycompany/payments/customer-credit-transfer/cbprplus/v1/customer-credit-transfers/6823985a-8205-45c2-a3d1-d7d239e3be10","mvc.controller.class":"HandlerFilterFunction$$Lambda$2149/0x0000000101020840"}},{"traceId":"b4a8d96f8f049083","parentId":"3247f662805eb1f3","id":"164994d6b875cc60","kind":"CONSUMER","name":"poll","timestamp":1655379023688055,"duration":1,"localEndpoint":{"serviceName":"transaction-search","ipv4":"10.129.12.174"},"remoteEndpoint":{"serviceName":"kafka"},"tags":{"kafka.topic":"SEARCH_REQUESTS"}},{"traceId":"b4a8d96f8f049083","parentId":"164994d6b875cc60","id":"55b5fcee3e3c49a4","name":"stream replay-filtering-transformer","timestamp":1655379023688807,"duration":38,"localEndpoint":{"serviceName":"transaction-search","ipv4":"10.129.12.174"},"tags":{"kafka.streams.application.id":"transaction-search","kafka.streams.task.id":"1_19"}},{"traceId":"b4a8d96f8f049083","parentId":"55b5fcee3e3c49a4","id":"3646e7a936c656fc","name":"stream processor-transformer","timestamp":1655379023688946,"duration":40698,"localEndpoint":{"serviceName":"transaction-search","ipv4":"10.129.12.174"},"tags":{"kafka.streams.application.id":"transaction-search","kafka.streams.task.id":"1_19"}},{"traceId":"b4a8d96f8f049083","parentId":"61c2a68f775a6d84","id":"88db7a613e308d38","name":"repository find-by-id","timestamp":1655379023690588,"duration":2527,"localEndpoint":{"serviceName":"transaction-search","ipv4":"10.129.12.174"},"tags":{"param.type=String":"6823985a-8205-45c2-a3d1-d7d239e3be10","repository.class":"CrudRepository","repository.method":"findById"}},{"traceId":"b4a8d96f8f049083","parentId":"1746e9eee2335668","id":"61c2a68f775a6d84","name":"service fetch-transaction-copy","timestamp":1655379023690538,"duration":2937,"localEndpoint":{"serviceName":"transaction-search","ipv4":"10.129.12.174"},"tags":{"param.type=String":"6823985a-8205-45c2-a3d1-d7d239e3be10","param.type=TransactionType":"CCTR","service.class":"DefaultTransactionSearchService","service.method":"fetchTransactionCopy"}},{"traceId":"b4a8d96f8f049083","parentId":"7f04035886ef53cd","id":"68a20dae4ad70cda","name":"repository find-all-by-transaction-id","timestamp":1655379023694675,"duration":2386,"localEndpoint":{"serviceName":"transaction-search","ipv4":"10.129.12.174"},"tags":{"param.type=String":"6823985a-8205-45c2-a3d1-d7d239e3be10","repository.class":"TransactionAttachmentRepository","repository.method":"findAllByTransactionId"}},{"traceId":"b4a8d96f8f049083","parentId":"1746e9eee2335668","id":"7f04035886ef53cd","name":"service fetch-all-grouped-by-type","timestamp":1655379023694581,"duration":2539,"localEndpoint":{"serviceName":"transaction-search","ipv4":"10.129.12.174"},"tags":{"param.type=String":"6823985a-8205-45c2-a3d1-d7d239e3be10","service.class":"DefaultTransactionAttachmentService","service.method":"fetchAllGroupedByType"}},{"traceId":"b4a8d96f8f049083","parentId":"b61012bc2370e82d","id":"68aaa41872600ac1","name":"repository find-all-by-transaction-id","timestamp":1655379023697784,"duration":1973,"localEndpoint":{"serviceName":"transaction-search","ipv4":"10.129.12.174"},"tags":{"param.type=String":"6823985a-8205-45c2-a3d1-d7d239e3be10","repository.class":"CommandAttachmentRepository","repository.method":"findAllByTransactionId"}},{"traceId":"b4a8d96f8f049083","parentId":"1746e9eee2335668","id":"b61012bc2370e82d","name":"service fetch-all-grouped-by-type","timestamp":1655379023697709,"duration":2109,"localEndpoint":{"serviceName":"transaction-search","ipv4":"10.129.12.174"},"tags":{"param.type=String":"6823985a-8205-45c2-a3d1-d7d239e3be10","service.class":"DefaultCommandAttachmentService","service.method":"fetchAllGroupedByType"}},{"traceId":"b4a8d96f8f049083","parentId":"6773f31956bd5a92","id":"18cab9e8422c9aa1","name":"repository find-all-by-transaction-id","timestamp":1655379023700533,"duration":4053,"localEndpoint":{"serviceName":"transaction-search","ipv4":"10.129.12.174"},"tags":{"param.type=Sort":"position: ASC","param.type=String":"6823985a-8205-45c2-a3d1-d7d239e3be10","repository.class":"AuditEntryRepository","repository.method":"findAllByTransactionId"}},{"traceId":"b4a8d96f8f049083","parentId":"1746e9eee2335668","id":"6773f31956bd5a92","name":"service fetch-all","timestamp":1655379023700385,"duration":4287,"localEndpoint":{"serviceName":"transaction-search","ipv4":"10.129.12.174"},"tags":{"param.type=String":"6823985a-8205-45c2-a3d1-d7d239e3be10","service.class":"DefaultAuditEntryService","service.method":"fetchAll"}},{"traceId":"b4a8d96f8f049083","parentId":"3646e7a936c656fc","id":"1746e9eee2335668","name":"processor process","timestamp":1655379023689052,"duration":40457,"localEndpoint":{"serviceName":"transaction-search","ipv4":"10.129.12.174"},"tags":{"param.type=DelegatingProcessorContext":"DelegatingProcessorContext{eventType=QUERY, applicationId=transaction-search, taskId=1_19, topic=SEARCH_REQUESTS, partition=19, key='6823985a-8205-45c2-a3d1-d7d239e3be10, headers=RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = kafka_origin, value = [81, 85, 69, 82, 89, 95, 71, 65, 84, 69, 87, 65, 89]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_replyTopic, value = [65, 80, 73, 45, 65, 68, 65, 80, 84, 69, 82, 45, 82, 69, 80, 76, 89]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_correlationId, value = [46, 30, 102, 109, -49, -23, 66, -45, -81, 6, 80, -40, 1, -106, 104, -122]), RecordHeader(key = x-request-id, value = [101, 53, 49, 97, 51, 52, 49, 51, 45, 48, 54, 50, 56, 45, 52, 100, 56, 100, 45, 97, 51, 100, 99, 45, 56, 51, 54, 56, 97, 50, 98, 99, 49, 52, 56, 52]), RecordHeader(key = swmsg.uetr, value = [54, 56, 50, 51, 57, 56, 53, 97, 45, 56, 50, 48, 53, 45, 52, 53, 99, 50, 45, 97, 51, 100, 49, 45, 100, 55, 100, 50, 51, 57, 101, 51, 98, 101, 49, 48])], isReadOnly = false), offset=1, timestamp=1655379022718}","param.type=GetTransactionById":"GetTransactionById(transactionType=CCTR, commandMetadata={"command_id":"e51a3413-0628-4d8d-a3dc-8368a2bc1484","command_type":null,"command_key":null,"command_status":"Received","transaction_id":"6823985a-8205-45c2-a3d1-d7d239e3be10","transaction_type":null,"flow_type":null,"flow_id":null,"flow_alternate_id":null,"creation_timestamp":"2022-06-16T11:30:22.716666Z","update_timestamp":"2022-06-16T11:30:22.71667Z","channel_info":{"sender_channel":"API","sender_dn":"ou=application,ou=payment,o=myprojectsbeaa,o=mycompany","sender_bic":null,"sender_role":null,"receiver_channel":null,"receiver_dn":null,"receiver_bic":null,"service_name":"mycompany.cbprplus.02","message_type":null,"is_technical_pde":null,"is_business_pde":null,"adapter_information":{"http_verb":"GET","uri":"/mycompany/payments/customer-credit-transfer/cbprplus/v1/customer-credit-transfers/6823985a-8205-45c2-a3d1-d7d239e3be10"},"command_expiry_time":null,"delivery_expiry_time":null},"resource_info":{"input_reference":"e51a3413-0628-4d8d-a3dc-8368a2bc1484","output_reference":null,"instruction_id":null,"uri":null,"output_id":null,"message_id":null},"command_result":null})","processor.class":"TransactionSearchQueryProcessor","processor.method":"process"}},{"traceId":"b4a8d96f8f049083","parentId":"3646e7a936c656fc","id":"823ec4521ca82b19","name":"stream processor-result-transformer","timestamp":1655379023729736,"duration":24,"localEndpoint":{"serviceName":"transaction-search","ipv4":"10.129.12.174"},"tags":{"kafka.streams.application.id":"transaction-search","kafka.streams.task.id":"1_19"}},{"traceId":"b4a8d96f8f049083","parentId":"823ec4521ca82b19","id":"644a18b6abe4eb27","kind":"PRODUCER","name":"send","timestamp":1655379023730597,"duration":7800,"localEndpoint":{"serviceName":"transaction-search","ipv4":"10.129.12.174"},"remoteEndpoint":{"serviceName":"kafka"},"tags":{"kafka.topic":"API-ADAPTER-REPLY"}},{"traceId":"b4a8d96f8f049083","parentId":"d52a186a817986f3","id":"4cf08e3b92f4cc14","kind":"CONSUMER","name":"poll","timestamp":1655379024629469,"duration":1,"localEndpoint":{"serviceName":"api-adapter","ipv4":"10.129.17.227"},"remoteEndpoint":{"serviceName":"kafka"},"tags":{"kafka.topic":"API-ADAPTER-REPLY"}},{"traceId":"b4a8d96f8f049083","parentId":"164994d6b875cc60","id":"55b5fcee3e3c49a4","localEndpoint":{"serviceName":"transaction-search","ipv4":"10.129.12.174"}},{"traceId":"b4a8d96f8f049083","parentId":"4b43ec0462bcb4e5","id":"3247f662805eb1f3","localEndpoint":{"serviceName":"transaction-search","ipv4":"10.129.12.174"}}]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by an incorrect definition of spans.
Some spans were created but not started and not finished in the finally clause. By fixing the code creating the span, the issue disappeared.